# MODX ExtJS backend компонент, выборка из таблиц

Tags: modx, extjs

Привет форумчане, вопрос к тем, кто знаком с MODX в значительной степени.
Т.к. я новичок в этой теме прошу не пинать.

С modExtra я более менее разобрался, имею вывод свой таблицы вида:

[image: https://file.modx.pro/files/2/7/a/27ace566e83f9758041efac35aab32a5.png]

Поля немного изменены:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id(AUTO_INCREMENT) | authorid | address |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Но мне нужно вывести вместо "authorid", "имя пользователя"(username) с таблицы modx_users у которого id=authorid.
Ломаю Голову. Подскажите люди добрые. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Добавляешь в процессоре `core/components/modextra/processors/mgr/item/getlist.php` джоин на таблицу modx_users с выводом необходимого тебе поля, и затем делаешь вывод этого поля в `assets/components/modextra/js/mgr/widgets/items.grid.js`.